# How to allow a Rigidbody to pass through another Rigidbody without stopping OnCollisionEnter from working

Tags: unity, virtual-reality

so im using Unity and im aware of the Physics page but it does make the Rigidbody pass through each other but it does not trigger OnCollisionEnter how can make it so the Rigidbody pass through eachother without disabling OnCollisionEnter?

Comment: Heyo, welcome to GameDev StackExchange! Be sure to check out [this page](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to ask a good question so you can have the best chance of getting an answer.

For now, though, your question is worded in a somewhat confusing manner. What exactly is the behavior that you want, and what are you getting instead?

Comment: We'll be able to help you more effectively if you can give us an idea of what these objects are, why they need to pass through each other, and why you want/need to detect this with OnCollisionEnter rather than eg. OnTriggerEnter.